# put a Popup window in android

Tags: android

I want to put popup window that I call from each `Activity` in my projects that has three button with `TextView` and want to get click event of that `Button`.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. Anyway, here's a blog post that may help you how to create a popup in Android: https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [Android Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html) documentation.

You can extend `Dialog` class to inflate your custom layout. Once you got it, you can show a new `Dialog` like this.-

```
Dialog dialog = new YourCustomDialog(this);
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a designated Dialog abstraction layer, in order to create dialogs and reuse them throughout the application. It uses the build in Dialog classes, but helps when I need to use the same dialogs in different activities.

An AlertDialog can display text and up to 3 buttons. Please see the class reference for handling of events:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html